# Understanding why the order of $3+\langle 6\rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{15}/\langle 6\rangle$ is $1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to understand the previous thread ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744625/find-the-orders-of-3-langle-6-rangle-and-2-langle-6-rangle-in-math)) which finds the order of $3+\langle 6\rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{15}/\langle 6\rangle$.

I was following the logic from that thread. First question is why in a group $(\mathbb{Z}_{15},+)$ we get:

$$(3+\langle6\rangle)^{n}=\underset{n\,times}{\underbrace{(3+\langle6\rangle)+(3+\langle6\rangle)+...+(3+\langle6\rangle)}}=3n+\langle6\rangle$$

An not $3n+n\langle 6\rangle$  (if we do get it and then why $n\langle 6\rangle =\langle 6\rangle$)?

Second question is about the line:

> Now note that the identity of $\mathbb{Z}_{15}/\langle 6\rangle$ is $0 + \langle 6\rangle = \langle 6\rangle$, so the order of $3 + \langle 6\rangle$ is the smallest positive integer $3n + \langle 6\rangle = \langle 6\rangle$.

What is the identity of $\mathbb{Z}_{15}/\langle 6\rangle$? Is it $0$ or $\langle 6\rangle$? I feel like the author wanted to point out that $\langle 6\rangle$ is the identity element but why $0$ is not? Also later it said that $3+\langle 6\rangle$ is the identity element. How is it possible to have more then one identity element in a group?

Last question is why $\langle 6\rangle=\{0,3,6,9,12\}$? From this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786452/how-to-find-a-generator-of-a-cyclic-group) I learn that if order of a group is $15$ then total number of generators of group $G$ are equal to positive integers less than $15$ and co-prime to $15$. So for example $3$ and $9$ are not in $\langle 6\rangle$.

I feel confused and it feels like I miss the definition of the cyclic group (even if it in front of me). Will be glad for some clarifications. Also, sorry for wasting time on explaining basic things.

Comment: $\langle 6\rangle$ is the smallest subgroup containing $6$. Keep adding $6+6+6+\cdots$, reduce modulo fifteen after each new term, and record the results. Those will be the elements of the subgroup.

Comment: We do have $\langle 6\rangle + \langle 6\rangle = \langle 6\rangle$, and not $\langle 6\rangle + \langle 6\rangle = 2\langle 6\rangle$. If you look at the definition of $+$ for subsets of an abelian group, and consider that $0\in \langle 6\rangle$, this fact will become clear. That being said, once you throw multiplication into the mix and get rings instead og groups, this would become a problem. Luckily, multiplication in a quotient ring is _specifically defined_ to make this perceived problem not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addition in a quotient group $\mathbb{Z}_{15}/\langle 6\rangle$ is *defined* as
$$(a+\langle 6\rangle) + (b + \langle 6\rangle) = (a+b) + \langle 6 \rangle$$
for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_{15}$. Hence no adding of $\langle 6\rangle$s.

On the other hand, equality in the quotient group is defined as $a + \langle 6\rangle = b + \langle 6\rangle$ if $a-b \in \langle 6\rangle$. The identity element of $\mathbb{Z}_{15}/\langle 6\rangle$ is $0 + \langle 6\rangle$, which is commonly denoted simply as $\langle 6\rangle$.

Let's determine $\langle 6\rangle$. Certainly $0,6 \in \langle 6\rangle$. Since a subgroup is closed under inverting we also have $-6 \in \langle 6\rangle$. But we have $-6 = 9$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ (the equality actually being congruence mod $15$) so $9 \in \langle 6\rangle$.

Since a subgroup is closed under addition, we have $12 = 6 + 6 \in \langle 6\rangle$. And then again $3 = -12 \in \langle 6\rangle$.

So far we got $\{0,3,6,9,12\} \subseteq \langle 6\rangle$. Now check that $\{0,3,6,9,12\}$ is indeed a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$, i.e. that the inverse of every element and the product of every two elements from the set stays in the set (working mod $15$ of course). Since $\langle 6\rangle$ is the *smallest* subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ containing $6$, we conclude $\langle 6\rangle \subseteq \{0,3,6,9,12\}$, and hence they are equal.

Finally, we see that $3 + \langle 6\rangle = 0 + \langle 6\rangle$ because $3-0 = 3 \in \langle 6\rangle$. Therefore $3 + \langle 6\rangle$ is indeed the identity element $\langle 6\rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{15}/\langle 6\rangle$.